An English magistrate's search warrant is authorised by a Scottish sheriff for execution in Scotland. What statute governs its execution?
An English magistrates' court grants English police a warrant to search premises in Scotland under section 8 of the Police and Criminal Evidence Act 1984. Execution of the warrant is then authorised by a Scottish sheriff, and subsquently the warrant actually is executed in Scotland.
What statute governs its execution and in particular the procedures that the police must follow?
Presumably the answer isn't PACE itself, because s8 of PACE applies only to England and Wales.

The answer is Scottish law, but I couldn't cite chapter and verse.

That's what I suspected, but I'd be interested in what specific Scottish statute governs the search. (Although if the police seize items having followed Scottish law, presumably they then have to follow PACE again if they take them - or information from them, or photographs - back to England. Recipe for a minefield!)

Related but not duplicate https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/97647/what-are-the-cross-jurisdictional-effects-of-british-police-powers
